# How do I get a rabbit to follow me?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering how do I can get rabbits to follow me so I can breed them. I have been experimenting with seeds, but they don't work. How do I do this?

Comment: Seeds = chickens

Answer (score 2):

You need [Carrots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Carrot), of course!

I mean, I suppose that [Dandelions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dandelion) work too, but... carrots!

Comment: You could also use a lead, which is isn't following in the sense of freewill...

Answer (score -1):

Hold a carrot and approach the rabbits they will begin to follow you, but if you don't have a carrot in your hand then they will run away.